# Virtualbox or VMware networking

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

**Background**
I have a lab setup in which the guest OS uses postfix as an MTA. Now my host is connected to a Terminal server which for now is on LAN (A lab). Guest has different servers which are needed for authentication, authorization, communication, scheduling...The only thing can't work is MTA because guest is bridged to LAN card.

**Question**
Is there any way that i can use the ethernet port for LAN connectivity and wireless for internet on guest?? like we can do on windows...

Answer (score 2):

A bridged virtual network adapter will not prevent Postfix from working. This is how most (if not all) virtualization schemes work to offer networking to guest OSes from limited host resources. VMware wouldn't have a business model if you couldn't share network hardware with many guest OSes.

Your Postfix setup is probably to blame.

To answer your question, **yes you can** assign certain kinds of "extra" host hardware to your guest OS. This is entirely incumbent on compatibility between the host OS, the virtualization solution, and the guest OS. It won't fix your Postfix problem, however.

Comment: Postfix is working when i am connected to internet...the question was simple that can i configure multiple adapters in virtualbox so that i can have internet connectivity with lab access...

Comment: At this point, it's very difficult to say what is possible or not without more details on your setup. Just remember that a virtual network adapter acts just like any other adapter on your physical network. It has its own MAC address and behaves independently of the physical adapter (except, of course, if the cable is unplugged).